# How to get the variable with its name in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, controls

Want to use a variable based on its name. It is hard to describe. Here is the example

```
var sections = new[] { "Personnel", "General", "Medical" };

foreach (var s in sections)
{
    // want to retrieve the variable "lblPersonnel"
    (Label)Type.GetType(string.Format("lbl{0}", s)).Text = "Test";
}
```

so that we don't have to :

```
lblPersonnel.Text = "Test";
lblGeneral.Text = "Test";
lblMedical.Text = "Test";
```

So, is it possible for this kind of "reflection"?

Comment: what is the type of TableCellPersonnel and what are you using, winForms or WPF ? explain your problem in more detail

Comment: sure let me update. Changed it into `lbl` for easier understanding.

Comment: Is `lblPersonnel` a _variable_ or a _member of the form_?  Variables aren't accessible through reflection but class members are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Type.GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) expects a *fully-qualified* type name but you are trying to pass it name of the variable.And also it returns a `Type` instance so you can't cast it to `Label`.It seems you are confused about types,instances and variables. If you have labels and you want to access them you can use `Controls` collection of your `Form`.

```
foreach (var s in sections)
{
   var name = string.Format("lbl{0}", s);
   if(this.Controls.ContainsKey(name))
   {
       var currentLabel = this.Controls[name] as Label;
       if(currentLabel != null) currentLabel.Text = "Test";
   }
}
```

Edit: If you are devoloping an `ASP.NET` project then you can use [`FindControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to get your labels by name:

```
foreach (var s in sections)
{
    var name = string.Format("lbl{0}", s);
    var currentLabel = FindControl(name) as Label;
    if(currentLabel != null) currentLabel.Text = "Test";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. stuck at `if(this.Controls.ContainsKey(name))` because I am on a report. How should we search for the control?

Comment: @Blaise If you are in a report, how do you want to have access to the controls to change their value?

Comment: How could I know that? why don't you specify it in your question ?

Comment: Sorry Selman22. I simplified the issue in the question. But thank you for the answer. I found out I could access `Controls` collection, though `ContainsKey` is not available. 

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just get the label using `Controls`?

```
var sections = new [] {"Personnel", "General", "Medical"};

foreach (var s in sections)
{
    // want to retrieve the variable "lblPersonnel"
    ((Label)(Controls["lbl" + s])).Text = "Test";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var s in sections)
{
    string name = string.Format("lbl{0}", s);
    FieldInfo fi = typeof(Form1).GetField(name);
    Label l = (Label)(fi.GetValue(this));
    l.Text = "Test";
}
```

This is assuming the `Label`s are public fields. If they are properties - use `GetProperty` , if they are private fields, use:

```
 GetField(name, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But what is this `SetValue(this, 5, null)`?

Comment: It sets the value of `this`'s `b`-property to 5.

Comment: See edit. This should work. I tested on a simple case.